# Which way to load navbar for user/admin in NodeJS/AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I have a request, Can anyone tell me, how to properly do. I want to make two navbars in my project, first is intended for admin, second for user. I use with NodeJS (back), AngularJS (front). At the moment I created on the side NodeJS script, Which checks the status of the user role:
In router index.js (I think its good place?)

```
router.get('/checkRole', function (req, res) {
    if (req.user != null) {
        if (req.user.role == 'admin') {
            res.json('admin');
        }
    } else {
        res.json('user');
    }
});
```

Now the question is what next?
Create Service with http.get to index route, and every time, when will be loaded page check status and load navbar?

(Important thing)
So I need in each controller to add a service (http get, check status, load navbar) yes?

Or is another way? Can someone explain me??

Sorry for english, and thanks for help.

Comment: You can add restrictions on your route config of Angular by resolving uisng your checkrole api(If you have separate pages for each role) OR you can change or include you navbar inside a single page by getting response from your checkrole api ..for eg - ng-if or nginclude on the basis of role.

Comment: But am I right to add service to all controllers and check roles?

Comment: No there is no need to add it in every controller.You can call that service once in your Main Controller which is applicable throughout your app and store it in global variable and access that variable wherever you want.I hope you get what i want to say.

Comment: Ok, Can You make code review ?? are makeing loop
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1d2c329b005a7a0892dffddb8ed42af4
When I add to   <body ng-controller="ListProductController" ng-include="navigation()" ng-init="initProducts()">

Comment: It should be something like inside your index.html/header.html(names are just for example) - `<div ng-if="$scope.navBar == 'user'">USER HEADER </div> ` and `<div ng-if="$scope.navBar == 'admin'">ADMIN HEADER </div> ` . have a look at gist.github.com/anonymous/1d2c329b005a7a0892dffddb8ed42af4